# Laravel: Multiple auth with same routes

Tags: laravel, authentication, routes

I have a Laravel(5.8) application where I have 2 roles `Super Admin` and `Admin` which are saved in two different tables `admins` & `users`. They each have their own access levels respectively. However, about 95% of the routes in the entire application are same for each of them but restricted or modified according to their access levels.

For example:
`Admin` can only update his own profile and has the permission to Create & View.
`Super Admin` can play with the list of `admins` and has the permission of create/update/view & delete.

Therefore I have two guards `users(default) = users table` and `admins = admins table`. But when I am adding both or the guards in a same controller it just keep redirecting and display that `the page is not redirecting properly`

**config/auth.php**

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver'   => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'member' => [
        'driver'   => 'session',
        'provider' => 'member',
    ],
    ...
],
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model'  => App\User::class,
    ],

    'member' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model'  => App\Member::class,
    ],
],
```

**User.php**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    ...

    public function _login($request)
    {
        if(\Auth::attempt([
            'email'    => $request->email,
            'password' => $request->password
        ]))
        {
            return [
                'success' => true
            ];
        }
        else
        {
            return [
                'success' => false
            ];
        }
    }
}
```

**Member.php**

```
class Member extends Authenticatable
{
    ...

    public function _login($request)
    {
        if(\Auth::guard('member')->attempt([
            'email'    => $request->email,
            'password' => $request->password
        ]))
        {
            return [
                'success' => true
            ];
        }
        else
        {
            return [
                'success' => false
            ];
        }
    }
}
```

**HomeController.php**

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        echo "<pre>";

        if(\Auth::user())
        {
            print_r(\Auth::user());
        }
        else if(\Auth::guard('member')->user())
        {
            print_r(\Auth::guard('member')->user());
        }

        echo "</pre>";
    }
}
```

If I comment the `auth` middleware in the `__construct()` then it works and displays the data of the logged in user but if keep redirecting and shows `the page is not redirecting properly` error.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `$this->middleware('auth:web')` or `$this->middleware('auth:member')` so your middleware knows which guard to use.

Anything after the `:` is passed to the Middleware's `handle()` function as arguments.

Comment: Thanks @Flame, I'll try this solution

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't work. I am still getting `the page is not redirecting properly` error.

Comment: you probably need to modify the `Authenticate` middleware then, and act accordingly to the guard you are given. It's a bit much to explain in a concise stackoverflow answer.